# Expressing a Polynomial in a certain form given two roots

Tags: polynomials

Two of the roots of the equation $ax^3+bx^2+cx+d=0$ are $-5$ and $6.$ Find an expression for the third root in terms of only $a$ and $c$ (that is, your expression should not involve $b$ or $d$)

How would I start on this problem? Rational Root Thereom. I can only think of RRT or drastic bashing.

Comment: Please try to make the titles of your questions more informative. For example, *Why does $a<b$ imply $a+c<b+c$?* is much more useful for other users than *A question about inequality.* From [How can I ask a good question?](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/589/): *Make your title as descriptive as possible. In many cases one can actually phrase the title as the question, at least in such a way so as to be comprehensible to an expert reader.* You can find more tips for choosing a good title [here](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/a/10144/).

Comment: Edited my Title.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use Vièta's formula:

$$x_1x_2+x_1x_3+x_2x_3={c\over a}$$ where $x_1=-5$ and $x_2=6$

And thus $$x_3 ={c\over a}+30$$

Comment: What? Firstly, it is asking for an expression. Also, isn't it Vietas Formula?

Comment: You can not finish it your self from here?

Comment: Think I got it :)

Comment: Thanks for downvoting.

Comment: I only downvoted your explanation because it seemed rushed. You didn't spell Vietas Formula correctly and do not seem on the track of finding the third root. $\frac{c}{a}$ is not the third root. Plus, I felt like this could be a comment.

Comment: @Bongocat you should be able to plug in $x_1=-5,x_2=6$ into the LHS and solve an arithmetic problem for $x_3$, no? That he misspelled could be because the answerer is not a native English speaker.

Comment: Oh, ok. I'm sorry about that. Upvoted.

Comment: I believe that [M. Viète](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/François_Viète) was French and Vieta was the Latinisation of his name. So for modern English speakers, [Vieta's formulas for the coefficients of polynomials in terms of their roots](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vieta%27s_formulas) and [Viète's formula for $\pi$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Viète%27s_formula) incorrectly appear (by historical convention) to be the work of two different mathematicians.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: if $r$ is the third root, you have:

$$
ax^3 + bx^2 + c^x + d = s(x + 5)(x - 6)(x - r)
$$

Expand the right-hand side and compare the coefficients.

Comment: Expanding would get $-r x s(x + 5) + 6 r s(x + 5) + x^2 s(x + 5) - 6 x s(x + 5).$

Comment: @Bongocat what are the coefficients on the resulting polynomial? you get 4 equations...

Comment: Isn't it just the coefficients of each of the expanded polynomial are equal to the original?

Comment: @Bongocat: yes, keep expanding and you'll get the equations you need. The right-hand side of these equations are instances of what are called the Vieta formulas.

Answer (score 0):

Let's call the 3rd root $r.$

$a(x-6)(x+5)(x-r) = ax^3 + bx^2 + cx + d$

Multiply out the LHS and isolate the $x$ term:

$a(- 6\cdot5 + 6\cdot r - 5\cdot r)x = cx\\
-30a + ra = c\\
r = \frac ca +30$